# How to logout all application

Tags: android

Good day...I working with two applications, and both applications a user have to be logged in.The first application after logging in,there is a button on click of the button,it forwards the user to the second application login. So now the user is logged in two different applications. So how can i logout both application on click of a logout button. I am able to logout for one application only.

This is my Code to logout for an application

```
 private void logOut() {

       mAuth.signOut();
        sendToLogin();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can register a broadcast receiver in both applications. On clicking the logout button, you can send this logout broadcast. On receiving this logout broadcast in onreceive method of the broadcast receiver call mAuth.signOut().

Comment: Thank you for your response, I am new to the course ,so please can you just give me an example